# Unity Camera Maintain perspective while rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I'm trying to write a camera script which will maintain the perspective point which I'm looking at while rotating.

```
public void RegisterRotationControls()
{
    var horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis(InputAxisName.Horizontal.ToString());

    offsetX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(horizontal * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offsetX;
    transform.position = player.position + offsetX;

    transform.LookAt(player.position + PlayerOffset);
}
```

Currently this script is only working properly when the camera is looking at the player, however the camera has freedom to move position yet the rotation should maintain relativity to the center.  [image]

The top row dipicts the current behavior, while the bottom depicts what should be occuring

Comment: Have you considered parenting the camera under an empty GameObject centered on the player, and just rotating that? Then you can have the camera pointing any which way, and still rotate it in a consistent circle around the player.

Comment: That sounds good, if I do that does the camera maintain its perspective in relation to the parent? And would I have to Decouple the parent from the camera to move the position, or can I move the position in relative to the parent

Comment: Well, you can move the camera as needed (probably locally, so it's moving relative to the parent's local space). Not entirely sure what you mean by the camera maintaining its perspective relative to the parent though - it should behave you shown in the second picture, but try it and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: @serlite thanks, your suggestion worked, if you post this as an answer I'll mark it as completed

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually calculating the rotation to move a camera in a circle while retaining its original (relative) facing is somewhat cumbersome, and requires you to do a lot more math than you need to.

A popular solution is to parent the camera under an empty GameObject, and centering that GameObject on the point/object you want the camera to rotate around. (This basically internalizes a lot of the calculations, letting the engine do the heavy lifting.) Then, you can locally translate the camera as needed and then rotate the container GameObject to move the camera in a circle.